# Update component by executing function in another

Tags: reactjs

Two components talking to each other, when adding a product to the cart (component # 1), update the setState, via service (component # 2).

When adding the product to the cart, an error returns, saying that I don't have access to the export function of component # 1.

#1 Component

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

import { Clipboard } from 'react-feather';
import { OrderCartButton } from './styles';
import OrderService from '~/services/orderservice';

import Context from '~/utils/context';

function OrderCart() {
  const { state, actions } = useContext(Context);

  function updateQty() {
    const qty = OrderService.count();
    actions({ type: 'setState', payload: { ...state, value: qty } });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    updateQty();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Link href="/order">
        <OrderCartButton data-order-qty={state.value}>
          <Clipboard />
        </OrderCartButton>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}

export default OrderCart;
```

#2 Component

```
import { reactLocalStorage } from 'reactjs-localstorage';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

class OrderService {
  async add(product) {
    const oldorder = reactLocalStorage.getObject('_order_meumenu');

    if (oldorder.length) {
      const merged = [...oldorder, ...product].reduce(
        (r, { id, qty, title, description, price, image }) => {
          const item = r.find((q) => q.id === id);
          if (item) item.qty += qty;
          else r.push({ id, qty, title, description, price, image });
          return r;
        },
        []
      );
      await reactLocalStorage.setObject('_order_meumenu', merged);
    } else {
      await reactLocalStorage.setObject('_order_meumenu', product);
    }
    toast.success('Produto adicionado ao Pedido');
    const qty = await this.count();
    return qty;
  },

  async count() {
    const order = reactLocalStorage.getObject('_order_meumenu');
    return order.length || 0;
  },
}

export default OrderService;
```

Component #3 - Context Moved to callback

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

import { Plus, Minus } from 'react-feather';
import { ProductContainer } from './styles';

import currency from '../../utils/currency';

import OrderService from '~/services/orderservice';
import Context from '~/utils/context';

function Product(product) {
  const { state, actions } = useContext(Context);

  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

  function addProductOrder(elem, elemQty) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    const newElem = [];
    newElem.push({ ...elem, qty: elemQty });
    OrderService.add(newElem).then((val) =>
      actions({ type: 'setState', payload: { ...state, value: val } })
    );
  }

  return (
    <ProductContainer>
      <div className="product-image">
        <img
          className="image"
          src={product.image}
          alt={product.title}
          data-product-image
        />
      </div>

      <div className="product-details">
        <div className="product-top">
          <div className="product-title">
            <span className="title" data-product-title>
              {product.title}
            </span>
            <span className="desc" data-product-desc>
              {product.description}
            </span>
          </div>

          <button
            type="button"
            className="product-add"
            onClick={() => addProductOrder(product, qty)}
          >
            <span className="btn -icon -rounded" title="Add Produto">
              <Plus className="icon" />
            </span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className="product-bottom">
          <div className="product-qty">
            <div className="product-control-number">
              <Minus className="icon" onClick={() => setQty(qty - 1)} />
              <input
                className="input"
                type="number"
                min="1"
                max="9"
                value={qty}
                readOnly
                data-number-value
              />
              <Plus className="icon" onClick={() => setQty(qty + 1)} />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            className="product-price"
            data-product-price={product.price}
            data-product-totalprice="9"
          >
            {currency(product.price)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ProductContainer>
  );
}

export default Product;
```

Comment: I recommend using React state or a state management library so that you don't have to trigger updates manually. That being said, the problem in your code is that you should import the `updateQty` function next to the OrderCart component: `import OrderCart, { updateQty } from '~/components/OrderCart';`

Comment: @Christiaan I made the change, but it continues with the same error return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to fix:

```
import OrderCart from '~/components/OrderCart';
// ...
OrderCart.updateQty();
```

the default export in `~/components/OrderCart` is the class component(`OrderCart`) and `updateQty` is another function in the same file, so the import statement should be something like:

```
import { updateQty } from '~/components/OrderCart';
```

and the usage should be

```
updateQty()
```

but this will not work because calling a function that returns some object will not cause a rerender.

So, to fix this you should pass a callback to the child component that calls the `add` function, and call the callback after invoking `add`.

The callback function to pass as props to the child can be `handleUpdateQty`.

Comment: Could you show me how to execute the callback, handleUpdateQty is not accessible.

Comment: @SHARKDEV pass `handleUpdateQty` as a prop to the child that calls `add` function. If the component that calls `add` is not a child to `OrderCart` then you can use [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: I'm a beginner in ReactJS, I come from php, I'm getting beaten in these more complicated phases, if I can help

Comment: @SHARKDEV edit your question and add the component that calls the `add` function.

Comment: @SHARKDEV Go through [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and add the context. Essentially, you just need to maintain the `qty` state in the context and `OrderCart` and `Product` should use the context for accessing/updating the products.